# NSString stringWithContentsOfURL is deprecated. What should I do?

Tags: xml, ios, nsstring, nsarray

I've written some code that uses `stringWithContentsOfURL`, but it turns out that it is now deprecated. Can you help me replace it? Here's my code:

```
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Additionally, can someone have some sample code to show how it works? What encoding was the original code done in (in my 2 lines above)?

I want to maintain compatibility so what should I choose for the encoding? What does error mean and what is it used for?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`

EDIT: Here's your code using the above method:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

You can change `NSUTF8StringEncoding` accordingly for whatever data you're importing.

Comment: If the data is coming from the web? such as http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv or http://localserver.local/myServices.php?q=1298&output=csv

Comment: If you're asking if `NSUTF8StringEncoding` will work for that, then yes it should work fine. Just copy and paste my code into your project and it should work 100%.

Comment: in the code provided, you used NSUTF8StringEncoding. Would I use this for all data transmitted over the web (like with Google Maps or another webserver)?

Comment: Yes, if it's text that you are reading. You can read more about UTF8 here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: Thanks EDC :-) I'll read up on that. What other encoding options are there?

Comment: There's a list of encodings in Apple's NSString class reference. Just look for `NSStringEncoding` in the Constants section. I've never needed to use anything other than UTF8 encoding, so I think you should be fine with that.

Answer (score 2):

The [NSString reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) says this:

> Use `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` or `stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` instead.

Comment: do you have sample code to show how it works? I am really confused. What encoding was the original code done in (in my 2 lines above)?