# When retrieving data from an RSS feed, is it possible to extract the actual body of the text?

Tags: objective-c, ios, rss

I've found several tutorials for making iphone apps that load data from an RSS feed, but they only extract the URL and then load the page from the internet in a WebView.

However, I would rather be able to extract the body text and pictures from the articles, so I can lay out the content myself with a design optimized for the iPhone.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

I found this code from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638909/nsstring-stringwithcontentsofurl-is-deprecated-what-should-i-do), which, from what I interpreted, is supposed to return the source code of the page as a string.

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

If I use this, parse the string for the code that contains the body text and pictures,  I should be able to get what I want. Would this be a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's technically possible. RSS is XML so use any XML parser you like on it to extract information. The real struggle will be working with what you have vs. what the design calls for. But to get started, just grab some example feeds and start hacking away at them with any parsers you'd like to try. NSXMLParser is built in, there are other good third party ones like RaptureXML.

Comment: I stumbled upon a code snippet from another SO question and posted it above. Would something like that work?

Comment: You'll need to be just a little more sophisticated and make sure the request is asynchronous - put it inside an NSOperationQueue for instance. Then you will need to parse, which is the hard part. Examine the RSS feeds you need to get your data from and just start hacking away at them.